# Cocos2D help: How to implement page flip or page curl in cocos2D?

Tags: iphone, algorithm, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing an interactive 2-book for children using cocos2D framework. It would be great to implement page curl in the e-book. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open your cocos2d-ios Xcode project, you will find a "TransitionsTest" target that will show you all default transitions in cocos2d; among them several page flips.

AFAIK, curl is not available by default; you could have a look at the ["Leaves" framework](https://github.com/brow/leaves) for an example of the logics behind page curl animation (Leaves does it for CoreAnimation, with page reflection and everything) and extend a cocos2d transition for your specific case.

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 3):

Page turning between scenes is available in Cocos2D as `CCTransitionPageTurn`.

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.5/interface_c_c_transition_page_turn.html